# python произведение степеней чисел

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

вводится последовательность, надо подсчитать произведение пятых степеней чисел в этой последовательности.

например 
ввод 1 1 2 1 
вывод 32

```
from numpy import product 
print(product(lambda x : x**5, map(int, input().split())))
```

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте преимущества Numpy - векторизированные функции:

```
import numpy as np

In [8]: inp = '1 1 2 1'

In [9]: a = np.array(inp.split()).astype(int)

In [10]: a
Out[10]: array([1, 1, 2, 1])

In [11]: np.power(a, 5).sum()
Out[11]: 35

In [12]: np.power(a, 5).prod()
Out[12]: 32

In [13]: np.power(a, 5)
Out[13]: array([ 1,  1, 32,  1], dtype=int32)

In [14]: a ** 5
Out[14]: array([ 1,  1, 32,  1], dtype=int32)
```

Если вам всенепременно надо все одним выражением сделать:

```
In [16]: np.power(np.array(input().split()).astype(int), 5).prod()
1 1 2 1
Out[16]: 32
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Используя numpy можно сделать немного короче:

```
import numpy as np
(np.array(input().split(), dtype=int)**5).prod()
```

Comment: Можно ещё короче, если убрать пробел перед `dtype` и вместо `np` написать `n` :)

Comment: @dimon можно, но это моветон)